How to connect between mesh and mesh smoothly and naturally

After merging multiple meshes, the mesh boundaries appear unnatural, as shown in the image. I would like to smooth out the mesh boundaries to make them look like a single, continuous mesh. How can I achieve this?

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.
